# Overlapping img using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to implement an effect on overlapping images so when I click and drag a bar the other image underneath should reveal modifying the width. My code works, but it's kind of buggy. When I click on the bar I have to then release it to make it work, so it's not really a drag, and it supposed to stop moving when I release the click.
And second, the bar goes right even outside my container. How could I fix my code?

```js
var up = $("#up");
var bar = $("#bar");
var container = $("#container");

bar.on("mousedown", function () {
    container.on("mousemove", function (e) {
        bar.css("left", e.clientX);
        up.width(e.clientX);
    });
});

$("body").on("mouseup", function () {
    container.off("mousemove");
});

container.on("mouseleave", function () {
    container.off("mousemove");
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
    height: 400px;
    width: 600px;
    object-fit: cover;
}

#up {
    width: 50%;
}

#bottom,
#up {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    border: 5px solid cornflowerblue;
    height: 410px;
    width: 610px;
}

#bar {
    position: absolute;
    height: 400px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: hotpink;
    left: 300px;
    cursor: e-resize;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="bottom">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=Image1" alt="image" />
            </div>
            <div id="up">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=Image2" alt="image" />
            </div>
            <div id="bar"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation** : When the bar was being slid, the images were acting as draggable elements. To stop that, I set `draggable` attribute to `false` in both image elements. Besides that, the blue color appearing was highlight because of selection of element. To prevent that, I set CSS property `user-select` to `none` for the container `divs` of images.

For browser compatibility, use different versions for `user-select`.

```js
var up = $("#up");
var bar = $("#bar");
var container = $("#container");

bar.on("mousedown", function() {
  container.on("mousemove", function(e) {
    let left = e.clientX;
    let containerWidth = container.width();
    let barWidth = bar.width();
    
    if((left + barWidth) > containerWidth)
      left = containerWidth - barWidth;
    
    bar.css("left", left);
    up.width(left);
  });
});


$("body").on("mouseup", function() {
  container.off("mousemove");
});

container.on("mouseleave", function() {
  container.off("mousemove");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#up {
  width: 50%;
}

#bottom, #up {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  user-select: none;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid cornflowerblue;
  height: 410px;
  width: 610px;
}

#bar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 400px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: hotpink;
  left: 300px;
  cursor: e-resize;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="bottom">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=Image1" alt="image" draggable="false"/>
  </div>
  <div id="up">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=Image2" alt="image" draggable="false"/>
  </div>
  <div id="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My advise is to NOT unregister (remove) the `mousemove` event listener.

Below, I used a `barActive` as a "flag" to know if the mouse button is down. The flag is resetted on `mouseup` and `mouseleave` of the `container`.

The `mousemove` event is a machinegun... But is still not fast enough to "really" follow the mouse. So if a user moves the bar fast, the cursor often is off the bar (I'm sure you noticed it). So a `mouseup` has good chances to not fire if the `mouseup` event listener is on the bar. So the event listener has to be on the container.

Now... While `mousemove` is not fast enought to follow the mouse perfectly... It often is too fast and may interfeer with the actions you wish to do with the other events, like `mousedown` were you set the "flag". At the same millisecond, you can have the `mousedown` event and multiple `mousemove` events. So to "isolate" it form the `mousemove` events, I used a real tiny `setTimeout`. That is giving enought time for the flag to be set bafore any next `mousemove` to enact.

About making sure the bar does not go outside the container, I used a condition on `e.clientX`.

I also took the container's `padding` in account.

```js
console.clear();

var up = $("#up");
var bar = $("#bar");
var container = $("#container");
var barActive = false;

bar.on("mousedown", function (e) {
  barActive = true;
});

container.on("mousemove mouseup mouseleave", function (e) {
  if (barActive && e.type === "mousemove") {
    setTimeout(function () {
      if (e.clientX < container.width() && e.clientX>5) {
        bar.css("left", e.clientX - 8);
        up.width(e.clientX - 8);
      }
    }, 1);
    return;
  }
  barActive = false;  // Applies only for mouseup and mouseleave
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
  object-fit: cover;
  user-select: none;  /* Prevents the image itself to be selected */
}

#up {
  width: 50%;
}

#bottom,
#up {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid cornflowerblue;
  height: 410px;
  width: 610px;
  overflow: hidden;  /* Will make sure the bar does not go over the border */
}

#bar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 400px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: hotpink;
  left: 300px;
  cursor: e-resize;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="bottom">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=Image1" alt="image" />
    </div>
    <div id="up">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=Image2" alt="image" />
    </div>
    <div id="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/jOVBYrR?editors=1111)